# A plugin for newsletter registration (not sending, just gathering data)?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, newsletter

Most of the plugins I see also send the newsletter, which I don't need. I need a simple, customizable plugin that helps me get user e-mails, name, and other custom fields, and store it in the database. The plugin must also have an unsubscribe option, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) is pretty flexible. And there's the premium plugin, [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/), which a lot of people love. Or if you don't really need to keep the subscriber info in your own database, you could always use a service like [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/), for which there are WordPress plugins available for subscriber sign-up.